# Type of variable changes based on access?

Tags: python, types, list-comprehension

I have a directed graph structure consisting of nodes and edges both of which subclass an Event parent class. Depending on external events, edges can either be active or inactive. I then find all the directed paths from a given node to the root node, but I really only care about the nodes along the way, not the edges. For instance, to convert from a set of edges to a set of nodes I use:

```
>>> paths
[[<Edge F>, <Edge B>]]
>>> lst = [set(map(lambda e: e.tail, path)) for path in paths]
```

where path is a list of edges. This is what confuses me: when I go to check the contents of `lst`, it changes depending on how I access it

```
>>> lst
[set([<Node 2>, <Node 1>])]
>>> [type(n) for n in path for path in lst]
[<class 'libs.network.Edge'>, <class 'libs.network.Edge'>]
>>> [type(n) for n in lst[0]]
[<class 'libs.network.Node'>, <class 'libs.network.Node'>]
```

Why aren't these two ways of accessing the type information the same?

Comment: You're not accessing the same thing in different ways, you're accessing different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your list comprehension order wrong. Nested loops are listed from *left to right*.

So the expression

```
[type(n) for n in path for path in lst]
```

is executed as

```
for n in path:
    for path in lst:
        type(n)
```

so `n` is taken from some random pre-assigned `path` variable you had before, and it is *that variable* that contains `Edge` instances. Those objects have *nothing* to do with the contents of `lst[0]` you loop over in your other expression.

You probably wanted to do this the other way around:

```
[type(n) for path in lst for n in path]
```

so that `path` is actually set from `lst` *before* you iterate over it.

Comment: I never would have caught that. Thank you. It is interesting that `path` had `Edge` instances because this was the first definition of `path` in that function body.

Comment: @CoconutBandit: it's probably a *global*, actually.

Comment: @CoconutBandit: although, in your demo session, `path` could be set from the `[set(map(lambda e: e.tail, path)) for path in paths]` expression, but only in Python 2 where list comprehensions don't have their own scope.

Comment: Yep, that would do it. I am using Python 2.